# configuring HTTP method on Apache2.22 on debian 7

Tags: apache, http, methods

I have google and read a few discussion threads but somehow I still can't quite get the configuration of http method working. Below are my config from /etc/apache2/sites-available/default .   I have also tried to edit my userdir.conf but no matter what I do , when i query my localhost:80, i always get back 4 allow methods GET,HEAD,POST,OPTIONS .  Can someone kindly point me out what I went wrong for the configuration?  I am trying to allow HTTP PUT here.

---

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

        DocumentRoot /var/www
        <Directory />
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride None
                Order Allow,Deny
                <Limit GET POST PUT DELETE>
                allow from all
                </Limit>
        </Directory>

        <Directory /var/www/>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                <Limit GET POST PUT DELETE OPTIONS>
                allow from all
                </Limit>
        </Directory>

        ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
        <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
                AllowOverride None
                Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

        # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
        # alert, emerg.
        LogLevel warn

        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

---

UserDir public_html
        UserDir disabled root

```
    <Directory /home/*/public_html>
            AllowOverride FileInfo AuthConfig Limit Indexes
            Options MultiViews Indexes SymLinksIfOwnerMatch IncludesNoExec
            <Limit GET POST OPTIONS DELETE>
                    Order allow,deny
                    Allow from all
            </Limit>
            <LimitExcept GET POST OPTIONS DELETE>
                    Order deny,allow
                    Deny from all
            </LimitExcept>
    </Directory>
```

---

```
root@debian-pre2:/var/log/apache2# dpkg -l |grep apache
ii  apache2                            2.2.22-13                     amd64        Apache HTTP Server metapackage
ii  apache2-doc                        2.2.22-13                     all          Apache HTTP Server documentation
ii  apache2-mpm-prefork                2.2.22-13                     amd64        Apache HTTP Server - traditional non-threaded model
ii  apache2-utils                      2.2.22-13                     amd64        utility programs for webservers
ii  apache2.2-bin                      2.2.22-13                     amd64        Apache HTTP Server common binary files
ii  apache2.2-common                   2.2.22-13                     amd64        Apache HTTP Server common files
ii  libapache2-mod-php5                5.4.4-14+deb7u5               amd64        server-side, HTML-embedded scripting language (Apache 2 module)
```

Comment: just stopping by years later.. i found a site discouraging the use of the limit directive altogether..

Comment: Don't use Limit/LimitExcept

The configuration blocks <Limit> and <LimitExcept> have very confusing semantics. If used wrongly, they can disable other, apparently unrelated authentication or authorization directives in your configuration. It's better to avoid them altogether. To disable the HTTP TRACE method, set TraceEnable off in conf.d/security. To disallow other methods, use mod_rewrite. If you really have to use Limit/LimitExcept, check that all your authentication/authorization is working as intended. 
(https://wiki.debian.org/Apache/Hardening)